# How to create secret in pre-install hook & delete after Helm uninstall

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I create a *K8S Secret* with Helm in a *pre-install hook*.

This secret is a random password for a database user. When I uninstall the Helm Chart I delete the database and the database user, so I'd like to delete the *K8S Secret* as-well.

Everything works fine, except the secret is not deleted after uninstallation.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret-name
  namespace: sample
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: "sample"
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: "sample"
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.1"
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-1"
type: Opaque
stringData:
  user: "test-user"
  password: {{ randAlphaNum 10 | quote }}
```

[In the documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/#hook-deletion-policies), there is the `hook-delete-policy` annotation, but the possible values are

- before-hook-creation
- hook-succeeded
- hook-failed

In my case, none of the options seem to be right.

How can I automatically delete the K8S Secret at uninstall time?

Comment: Did the solution of @Daniel Marques help you?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `post-delete` along with `pre-install`?

> post-delete   -- Executes on a deletion request after all of the
> release's resources have been deleted

```
annotations:
  "helm.sh/hook": post-delete
  "helm.sh/hook": pre-install
```

Comment: so `post-delete` deletes the resource if it is not `Job`, and create the resource if it is `Job`?

Comment: it seems not illegal to have duplicate key in `annotations`

Comment: `post-delete` means the resource will get created post deletion of resources. This answer is incorrect.